# How to make NodeJS Server deployed on AWS cloud go live?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04

I am new to NodeJS.
I have the following code for hello world.

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('Hello World!\n I am the AWS cloud');
    }).listen(8081);
console.log('Server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8081');
```

This code is saved on my AWS cloud which runs an Ubuntu 14.04 instance.
I have installed nodeJS on Ubuntu.
When I run the code it works fine and displays the console log message, but when I open a web browser on a different machine and type http://Public-IP-Address:8081 it does not work.

Also when I stop the script by pressing Ctrl+c and then again execute it, it displays the following error message:

```
Server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8081
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1156:14)
    at listen (net.js:1182:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1267:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/NodeJSscripts/hw.js:17:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

When I go back and change the port number and run the script again, it then runs again without throwing any error, but the web browser still doesn't connect to the server through it's public IP.

Comment: Do you have a security group setup to allow requests to the server on your target port?

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to ask here, but I am working from behind a corporate network here, if thats what you mean.

Comment: If you're using an EC2 server, it comes with a pre-configured security group. That's the security group i'm talking about.

Comment: So if i configure the security group correctly, the above mentioned issue would go away ?

Comment: Possibly, assuming your local network isn't blocking it. :)

Comment: but, the security group won't fix whatever is causing the `EADDRINUSE`. that shouldn't be happening on closing the server, it should only be happening when you start it.

Comment: Exactly I get the `EADDRINUSE` error only when I try to restart the server.

Comment: Are you sure you stopped the node process first? that error only occurs when you try to use an ip/port combo that is already in use.

Comment: I stop the script to modify it and restart it to see the changes and thats when I see the error.

Comment: My guess is it didn't properly stop for 
some reason.

Comment: Yup configuring the security ports did work !!